# fsevents is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

Starting the development server...

```
/Users/puneetrangrass/Documents/react/react-practice/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:28
return (new fsevents(path)).on('fsevent', callback).start();
^
TypeError: fsevents is not a constructor
at createFSEventsInstance (/Users/puneetrangrass/Documents/react/react-practice/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:28:11)
at setFSEventsListener (/Users/puneetrangrass/Documents/react/react-practice/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:82:16)
at FSWatcher.FsEventsHandler._watchWithFsEvents (/Users/puneetrangrass/Documents/react/react-practice/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:252:16)
at FSWatcher. (/Users/puneetrangrass/Documents/react/react-practice/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:386:25)
at LOOP (fs.js:1570:14)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-practice@0.1.0 start: react-scripts start
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-practice@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/puneetrangrass/.npm/_logs/2019-07-13T05_06_50_503Z-debug.log
puneets-MacBook-Pro:react-practice puneetrangrass$ node --v
node: bad option: --v
puneets-MacBook-Pro:react-practice puneetrangrass$ node -v
v10.16.0
puneets-MacBook-Pro:react-practice puneetrangrass$
```

in my machine

node : v10.16.0
npm : 6.9.0

while executing " npm start " in react app. how can i resolve the issue?

Comment: Try `npm install` first and then `npm start`

Comment: @ravibagul91tried but the same issue occurs.

Comment: Then you must re install fsevents - `npm i fsevents`

Comment: This is known bug - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6891

Comment: 1.  I deleted my react app because I realized I did not have yarn installed.
 
2: So I installed yarn.

3: Then, again I did npx create-react-app my-app, and it worked. The issue disappeared.

what is the issue with the npm ?

@ravibagul91

Comment: `npm` by default installs the latest versions of dependencies which might not get supported some times.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error:

> TypeError: fsevents is not a constructor

Solution:

Inside any created project that has not been ejected, run:

```
npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@3.0.1
```

or:

```
yarn add --exact react-scripts@3.0.1
```

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v3.0.1